# Почему таблица содержит >= 25 < tr >

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Добрый день!
Собственно проблема в то что при запуске данного безобразия отображаются таблицы с рандомно генерируемыми людьми, но в таблице отображается не более 25 рядов таблицы, какой бы rand(x,y); все равно 25 рядов или меньше.

Заранее спасибо.

```
<?php
require_once('./dbconn.php');
// name class_1a


$subclasses = 'abcdefgh';
$subclasses = str_split($subclasses);

//echo $subclasses[];
$boys_names = "Иван, Петр, Владимир, Андрей, Александр, Анатолий, Алексей,         Николай, Сергей, Василий, Антон, Юрий, Константин, Дмитрий";
$boys_names = explode(", ",$boys_names);


$lastname_main = "Иванов, Петров, Сидоров, Камушкин, Молочков, Оглоблин, Стаканников, Сталин, Ленин, Дуров, Путин, Карагодин, Макунин, Попов, Акабосов";
$lastname_main = explode(", ",$lastname_main);

$lastname_boys = $lastname_main;
foreach($lastname_main as $one){
    $lastname_girls[] = $one."а";
}


$girls_names = "Татьяна, Таисия, Екатерина, Елена, Наталья, Анастасия, Алёна, Ольга, Евгения, Инна, Мария, Марина, Галина, Яна, Юлия, Надежда, Анна, София";
$girls_names = explode(", ",$girls_names);
$patronim_main = "Иванов, Петров, Владимиров, Андреев, Александров, Анатольев, Алексеев, Николаев, Сергеев, Васильев, Антонов, Юрьев, Константинов, Дмитриев";
$patronim_main = explode(", ",$patronim_main);

foreach ($patronim_main as $one){
    $patronim_boys[] = $one."ич";
    $patronim_girls[] = $one."на";
}

for($i = 0; $i <4; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < rand(1,4);$j++){
        $listclasses[] = "class_".($i+1).$subclasses[$j];
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($listclasses); $i++){
    echo "<table>";
    echo $listclasses[$i]."</br>";

for($j = 0; $j< rand(20,30);$j++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
    echo $j." </td><td> ";
    $sex = rand(0,1);
    if($sex === 0){
        echo $lastname_girls[rand(1,count($lastname_girls)-1)]."</td><td> ".$girls_names[rand(1,count($girls_names)-1)]."</td><td> ".$patronim_girls[rand(1,count($patronim_girls)-1)];
    }
    else{
        echo $lastname_boys[rand(1,count($lastname_boys)-1)]."</td><td> ".$boys_names[rand(1,count($boys_names)-1)]."</td><td> ".$patronim_boys[rand(1,count($patronim_boys)-1)];

    }
    echo"</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
}

//$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $class "


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    table{
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    tr>td{
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вы бы для начала `rand` из условия цикла `j < rand` убрали бы, а то оно на каждой итерации разное у вас.

Comment: ну то есть не для начала, а в принципе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в цикле

```
for($j = 0; $j< rand(20,30);$j++){
```

значение `rand` вычисляется на каждой итерации. В принципе можно получить и более 25 строк, просто надо больше обновлений страницы сделать.

вынесите количество в отдельную переменную

```
$len = rand(20,30);
for($j = 0; $j < $len; $j++){
    .....
```